# Image in the DIV sometime not showing

Tags: jquery

I am facing a weird scenario about the GIF image sometime show up and sometime is not show up in the DIV. I think I did something wrong with code.  Let me explain....

I have a file name called "funcJquery.js" and in that file I have this code below:

```
// Function - Diaglog box.
progressCircle = function()
{       
    $('<div id="myDivProgressPlugIn" class="divProgressCirclePlugIn" style="text-align:center; color:darkgray;"  style="border-radius:30px;height:100px;width:100px;">' +
            "Please wait!  Processing ... <br /><br />" +
           '<img src="/include/images/progress_indicator.gif"  alt="divProgressCirclePlugIn"/>' + 
            "</div>").appendTo('body')
        .dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: true,
        }).siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();

    }
```

In my page (says "index.html") has this code to include that file and Jquery:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/jquery/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/Jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/Jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/funcJquery.js"></script>
```

Then I have two buttons, "Approve" and "Deny".  Each button is in a separate form (you can see in my Jquery code below):

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Deny").on("click", function()
    {
        //alert("test1");
        progressCircle();
        document.forms["form2"].submit();
        return false;

    })

    $("#Approve").on("click", function()
    {
        //alert("test1");
        progressCircle();
        document.forms["form1"].submit();
        return false;

    })
});
</script>
```

When I click either the "Approve" or "Deny" buttons, it actually loads the dialog DIV "myDivProgressPlugIn" in the include file (funcJquery.js).  It also shows the message "Please wait! Progressing ..."  However, sometime it shows the image "progress_indicator.gif" and most of the time it shows the class name "divProgressCirclePlugIn" instead of the GIF.  I couldn't figure out what is wrong with it.  Please help or advise what I should try.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just a tip, to include the div into the document when the page is loaded and set its `display: none` initially. Also preloading the image so that it is displayed instantenously, a few tips for preloading are [here](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/).

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  What I try to do is not include the DIV in every pages.  Instead, I include the "funcJquery.js" and just call the function "progressCircle" to load the progress bar.

Comment: I found the solution and it is working now.  Can someone please show me how to close this post in the correct way? Thanks

Comment: The correct way to close your question would be to post the answer and then accept it, I think.